# Variavel vazia - PHP

Tags: php

Tenho duas páginas (index.php) e (relatorio.php). O index.php tem um modal que pega os dados digitados pelo usuário (data de inicio e data final). Mediante a estas informações imputada, é direcionado ao relatorio.php. O problema que as variaveis não estão sendo alimentadas no relatorio.php, gerando o erro abaixo:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Se eu acesso o relatorio.php e coloco no $sql um valor fixado, o relatório é gerado sem problemas, porem se depender dos valores imputados pelo usuário, o relatório é gerado em branco.

```
relatorio.php




 <?php

#include("conexao.php");
include("mpdf.php");

$grupo = selectAllPessoa();
$datainicio = $_POST['starts_at'];
$datafim = $_POST['ends_at'];

function abrirBanco(){
    $conexao = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxxx", "xxx");
    return $conexao;
}


function selectAllPessoa(){
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = ("select * FROM xxxx WHERE resolution BETWEEN ('$datainicio') AND ('$datafim')");
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

      $grupo[] = $row;
    }
   return $grupo;
}

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode("fullpage");
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1>Relatorio - Denuncia</h1><hr/>");

$html = "<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nickname</th>
                    <th>Sala</th>
                    <th>Data </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
               foreach ($grupo as $pessoa) {
$html = $html ."    <tr>
                    <td>{$pessoa["nickname"]}</td>
                    <td>{$pessoa["sala"]}</td>
                    <td>{$pessoa["resolution"]}</td>
                     </tr>";
}
          $html = $html ."  </tbody>
        </table>";

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente as datas de inicio e de final não estão vindo em um formato aceito pelo banco de dados, por isso não retorna nenhum registro no método `selectAllPessoa()`. O padrão de datetime aceito pela maioria dos bancos de dados é `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` (Exemplo: 2018-02-16 16:06:20). Verifique se o valor do POST está vindo neste mesmo formato.

Agora sobre o erro:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

No método `selectAllPessoa()`, inicie a variável `$grupo` como um **Array vazio**, assim:

```
function selectAllPessoa(){
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = ("select * FROM xxxx WHERE resolution BETWEEN ('$datainicio') AND ('$datafim')");
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    $grupo = array(); // <- Adicione esta linha
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

      $grupo[] = $row;
    }
   return $grupo;
}
```

Isso faz com que a variável enviada para o foreach seja um array de qualquer forma, evitando esse erro.

Comment: Inclui a linha sugerida e o erro não ocorre mais, porem o relatório ainda permanece em branco. O formulário está enviando no formato certo 0000-00-00.Creio que ele não está recebendo os valores do post.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, inseri as variávels  $datainicio = $_POST['starts_at'];
    $datafim = $_POST['ends_at']; dentro da função selectAllPessoa () e resolveu. Obrigado pela atenção.